# Make my javascript code automated and not locally?

Tags: javascript, automation, cloud

I created a google extension using javascript to make a specific task on a website every time I open it, but now I want the code to run on that page without having to even open my PC like cloud run or something. How can I do that?

Comment: Create a server that runs your function on an interval and automates a headless browser if necessary.

Comment: Depends on what it does.  If it's just to POST data, then you could recreate that data in a [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/curl/info) request and add it as a scheduled task / cron entry.

Comment: It's to click on a specific place in a website every time interval